# Find the existence intervals of objects given Boolean evaluation of objects over time

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, mathematical-modeling

I came up with this problem just out of curiosity, thus I'm not really sure how to properly phrase/tag it, so my apologies for the clumsy expression.

Let say I have a set of objects $A=(a,b,c,\dots,n)$ observed over a period of time $T$. Each object is associated with some time intervals representing its existence duration, say the isomorphic set $I=(i_a,i_b,\dots,i_n)$, with $i_a=(t_{a1},t_{a2},\dots)$, and $t_{aj}$ representing some time intervals in $T$. Given a Boolean evaluation function $f:(A\times T)\to \{0,1\}$ on the existence of the object at certain time instance $t$ in $T$, can I constructing an isomorphism between $A$ and $I$ based on $f$? I'm thinking of something along the lines of the union of the inverses of $f^{-1}$, but not really sure how to write a consistent inverse of Cartesian product.

Edit (This example is in the comment, I'm just moving it here for better clarification): For example, I have 3 atoms (a,b,c) over a period t = (0, 5). I have a function f that tells me if these atoms exist at some time t1 or not (for example, f(a, 1) means at the time instance 1, atom a do exist). Now, I want to find some mapping g(a) based on f such that, for example, g(a) = ((0.5, 1.2), (1.5, 3), etc.).

Comment: What do you mean by an isomorphism between $A$ and $T$?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean by "the union of the inverses of $f^{-1}$" or by "a consistent inverse of Cartesian product".

Comment: Oh it should have been between $A$ and $I$. I just editted it

Comment: Oh, ok. And by isomorphism, you just mean bijection? Don't you already know $A$ and $I$ are in bijection? The elements of $I$ are indexed by the elements of $A$...

Comment: What I imagine is, for example, $f^{-1}(1, t)$ would be a function that shows the list of all objects that exists at instance t. If that is the case, then the union of $f^{-1}(1, t)$ from $t_1$ to $t_2$ would returns all the objects that exists in that interval. However, I don't think the Cartesian products can have inverses - so should I model this problem differently?

Comment: Yes, we know that is the case, but we don't know the mapping. For example, I have 3 atoms (a,b,c) over a period t = (0 , 5). I have a function f that tells me if these atoms exist at sometime $t_1$ or not (for example, f(a, 1) means at 1s, atom a do exist). Now, I want to find some mapping g(a) based on f such that, for example, g(a) = ((0.5, 1.2), (1.5, 3), etc.). Does that make sense?

Comment: Also, I didn't specify the operation on $I$, but I think it should be straightforward that it would be the union of time-interval. So in that case, it would be an isomorphism, since all the duration that, say a or b exists, is the same as the union of duration that a exists or b exists

Comment: I recommend you edit your question to try to make it clearer what you're looking for. It would be a good idea to edit the example from your comment into the question. If you're not sure how to phrase something precisely, giving examples is a lot more helpful than guessing what terms to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what you mean in the example, but it is by no means an 'isomorphism between $A$ and $I$'.

Given $f:A\times T\to\{0,1\}$ you seem to be looking for $g:A\to \mathcal P(T)$ which assigns $$g(a)\ =\ \{t\in T:f(a,t)=1\}\,.$$
If you insist, you can write it in a less readable formula with an inverse of $f$:
$$g(a)=\pi_T\left(f^{-1}(1)\,\cap\, \pi_A^{-1}(a)\right)$$
where $\pi_T,\pi_A$ are the projections from $A\times T$.

Or, define $f_a:=t\mapsto f(a,t)$ for each $a\in A$, and then we can write
$$g(a)=f_a^{-1}(1)\,.$$
Note that it depends on $f$ whether these subsets of $T$ are indeed a union of disjoint intervals or not.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense now. I don't think it's a difficult problem, but I'm just not aware of the ways you can write math notation of inverse cartesian product that is well-defined